# CURL Response handling

Tags: php, json, curl

I have received the JSON response for my curl request, in the response, there are links which need to be opened automatically. In my case I need to open the links manually, can someone please assist me on this

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, as i am new to this domain, bit confused. I am rephrasing my question...Through curl post, i have sent some parameters to Payment gateway for that i have received payment link in JSON response. I have added the below mentioned snippets to redirect to the page automatically but it does not work.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($payment_links,'WEB',TRUE);
return $result;